# App with UINavigationController and UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've been struggling around for some time with this problem. I got it working but not the way it should and I guess its because Im doing it wrong. My goal is to have the following layout.

I have a Main Menu with four buttons. Clicking on each shows a different TableView (I should have a back button in the right corner of the navController, to be able to go back to the main menu, but I don't). Each of these TableViews are inside a UITabBarController (looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkFwo.jpg)

So how do I have to do this?

This is my current code (definitely wrong at some point(s))

```
- (IBAction)MyButton:(id)sender
{
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3, *viewController4;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    viewController1 = [[[LexikonControllerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LexikonControllerViewController" bundle:nil] setArrays:PflanzenIDs List:ListOfPlants Index:IndexOfPlants dict:DictionaryOfPflantsAndIDs];
}

UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1, nil];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.view.frame;
frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 20;
self.tabBarController.view.frame = frame;

[self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
}
```

EDIT:

Now I tried this:
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
    {
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

```
vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[vc setTitle:@"Home"];
[vc setParent:self];

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

UITabBarController *tb = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSArray *controllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, nil]];
tb.viewControllers = controllers;

[window addSubview:[tb view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Problem: on the main view (with the main menu) I can see the tab bar (which shouldnt be there) and using hidesBottomBarWhenPushed hides the tabbar completetely on all other views :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it. What I did was set up my Main menu as root view for the navigationcontroller and if I click on one of the buttons I load a new UIViewController which takes care of setting up a TabBarController and load my four different tableviews in each Tab.
All of this without storyboard and XIBs.

Comment: Hi Daniel, is it possible to paste the code of the AppDelegate please? to see how the NavigationController is set as the rootViewController which controls several different UITabBarControllers please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand same as @lionfly.

Answer (score 1):

The tab bar controller should be your root view controller.  You could also hook this up within a storyboard.

Comment: but isnt it that way? could you be more specific (using my code)? thx

Comment: Are you using storyboards?  If so, you shouldn't need to alloc/init your VCs, I think that the storyboard should do this for you.  Unless you are trying to do something funky, you shouldn't need to mess around with the window either - this is probably the wrong track.  Check out the Apple Developer docs for storyboards and view controllers, or a storyboard tutorial such as http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1